# magento 2.3 - Get cart info after user login

Tags: magento2.3, cart, customer-login

my goal is to modify info on cart after user has logged in, either from account page or cart popup.
So, I created a new module for this, using the event "customer_login" but it does not seem to work.
Could you please let me know if this is the right event to use to intervene on cart after login?

Thank you very much for your help

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="cart_preorder" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**module.xml**

```
---
<sequence>
     <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
</sequence>
---
```

**Observer**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart;

class CustomObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $cartHelper;

    public function __construct(
      \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
      \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
    ) {
      $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
      $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
      $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();       
      $customerId = $customer->getId();
      die(print_r($customerId));
      if($customerId){            
         $customerQuote = $this->quoteRepository->getForCustomer($customerId);
         $cartItems = $customerQuote->getAllItems();
         die($cartItems);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **customer_data_object_login** event.

Check the following class:

> vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php

```
public function authenticate($username, $password)
{
    try {
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($username);
    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid login or password.'));
    }

    $customerId = $customer->getId();
    if ($this->getAuthentication()->isLocked($customerId)) {
        throw new UserLockedException(__('The account is locked.'));
    }
    try {
        $this->getAuthentication()->authenticate($customerId, $password);
    } catch (InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $e) {
        throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid login or password.'));
    }
    if ($customer->getConfirmation() && $this->isConfirmationRequired($customer)) {
        throw new EmailNotConfirmedException(__("This account isn't confirmed. Verify and try again."));
    }

    $customerModel = $this->customerFactory->create()->updateData($customer);
    $this->eventManager->dispatch(
        'customer_customer_authenticated',
        ['model' => $customerModel, 'password' => $password]
    );

    $this->eventManager->dispatch('customer_data_object_login', ['customer' => $customer]);

    return $customer;
}
```

Comment: This actually worked! Thanks!